# Releasing managed objects in static clasess

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, memory-management

What is the best practice to free managed objects in static/shared classes?

I am holding 3 large datatables and don't use them most of the time.

GC will not release them because they are static - am I right?

I was wondering if setting them to null in `ReleaseDatatables()` will be useful or am I just wasting my time?

Thank you.

```
public static class Helpers 
{
    private static DataTable _branchDT;
    public static DataTable branchDT
    {
       get
       {
           if (_branchDT == null)
           {
               _branchDT = new DataTable();
               _branchDT = Orange.ProjectManagment.DAL.Database.getDataset("SELECT * FROM Branches").Tables[0];
               return _branchDT;
           }
           else
           {
               return _branchDT;
           }
       }
       set { _branchDT = value; }
   }

   private static DataTable _departmentDT;

   public static DataTable departmentDT
   {
       get 
       {
           if (_departmentDT == null)
           {
               _departmentDT = new DataTable();
               _departmentDT = Orange.ProjectManagment.DAL.Database.getDataset("SELECT * FROM Departments").Tables[0];
               return _departmentDT;
           }
           else
           {
               return _departmentDT;
           }
       }
       set { _departmentDT = value; }
   }

   private static DataTable _TeamsDT;

   public static DataTable TeamsDT
        {
            get
            {

                if (_TeamsDT == null)
                {
                    _TeamsDT = new DataTable();
                    _TeamsDT = Orange.ProjectManagment.DAL.Database.getDataset("SELECT * FROM Teams").Tables[0];
                    return _TeamsDT;
                }

                else
                {

                    return _TeamsDT;
                }

            }

            set { _TeamsDT = value; }
        }


       /// <summary>
       /// setting all datatables to null in order to free memory or to make them refresh them self in the next call to get property method
       ///
       /// </summary>
       public static void ReleaseDatatables()
        {
                // datatables set to null, hence next call to them they will refresh via new query to db in get prop method
                branchDT = null;
                departmentDT = null;
                TeamsDT = null;
        }
```

Comment: _"i am holding 3 large datatables and dont use them most of the time" So why do you store them at all?_ Ask the database for data _when you need it_, don't keep old data in memory.

Comment: i considered that as an option but still wondering if setting them to null is useful

Comment: Caching data is sensible when it is expensive to create and cheap to keep around.  DataTable has the distinction that it is both expensive to create and usually expensive to keep around.  Depending on the number of rows, a number that never gets less.  Data items like teams, branches and departments should however have a reasonable upper bound.  The only other concern then is that your data might easily get stale when the dbase tables change.  Making the decision is a programmer's job, we can't do it for you.

Comment: According to MS use a method when "The operation is expensive enough that you want to communicate to the user that they should consider caching the result.". For details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d(VS.71).aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GC checks "roots" when calculating an information about whether it can release memory or not. And if any reference type variable is tied to the root, then object isn't collected.

Your static objects are ones of this roots, so if you set null to your variables, your big data won't be tied to roots and will be released.

Also, you can take a look on the [WeakReference object types here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) 
It's an another approach for your case

---

**Update**

But your solution doesn't seem to be best practice for me. It's very dangerous to read all data from the db table since you don't know how much data is stored there. It's better to make your properties IEnumerable and use "yield return" with chunks of data without this caching. Depends on the context of what you are trying to do of course.

Comment: thank you , i will espouse the practice you wrote on the update section.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But static classes don't need to be released.

Static classes don't need to be released, since they are not objects and they don't consume memory.

Static fields in static classes are objects that consume memory. They won't be released since they are accessible until the application is closed.
If you want to free up some memory set the field to null.